# A Huge Database: Picking the right schema and data model

Tags: database-design, scalability

We want to store some genomic variant data but there are some problems, more important ones like problem of the data's immense size and variability.

1. Variant data can be huge.  For example, a single individuals variant data could feasibly some day require a million rows of data in a table, or require of a gigabyte of raw storage on disk.  Multiply this over several thousand individuals, and you could potentially end up with terabytes worth of information that you need to make sense of.
2. Each client and/or system we integrate with, will expose or want to see data slightly differently depending on their needs and use cases.  This can potentially lead to hundreds of fields that we might need to store, all of which might need to be in different configurations based on the clients needs. So this variant data model will need to keep this in mind in order to remain easy to use, expandable and most
   importantly, scalable in the long term.

What do you think is better for such a problem? We were thining of having some coulmns in each table that point to an external database or even a file, where we save the huge BLOB data?

Comment: Could you use views or even just queries/procs to resolve your second issue?

Comment: @MichaelK Yeah but aren't they bad for performance?

Comment: You might want to ask to have this question migrated to http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: While I'm sure there is some leg work that you can do ahead of time trying to pick the *right* schema and data model, I think it might be best if you initially created and E-R diagram (or something like that) to understand what your data needs really are. You aren't going to be able to answer these kinds of questions with vague general details.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner I asked the DBA mods but haven't gotten a response yet.  This is in my opinion an important design question so it is on topic here, but I just feel that the OP might have gotten a better answer on DBA than here.

Comment: @maple_shaft: Thanks all, Yeah I still think this is a better place, it is a design decision, not a database maintenance decision..so hopefully I will get better ideas in programmers site...

Comment: @maple_shaft: There's a `database design` tag on that site, so I think it could be equally fitting there, and maybe more exposure to people who might be better able to answer, as this seems to me to be a bit outside most programmers' database experiences.

Comment: @maple_shaft I think this is reasonable on either site. I have a feeling the best answer for this is going to be a NoSQL solution, and so for that reason alone I want it on [dba.se]

Comment: @BDotA use the right tool for the right problem. In this case that's NoSQL for what this sounds like (lots of variant data and lots of random fields, based on the site. That's very easily done with some NoSQL solutions)

Comment: @jcolebrand: Why not expand this into a full answer?

Comment: @jcolebrand : Thanks, I will lookup NoSQL, don't know what it is right now :(

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner to give better experts than me the chance for it to be visible? Because I'm kinda swamped right now at work and was tossing my $0.05 as a [dba.se] mod? :-\ both crappy reasons, but true.

Comment: @BDotA read this http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/607/what-is-a-key-value-store-database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know enough about your system but you need to look at the following:

1-How you obtain the data and in what format? Answering this will give options of how to store it and load it initially if you will end-up using a database.

2-How do you process this raw data? Answering this, will help you figure the 'active' set size. This will help in deciding how to store and how to load the data also. You may find that you don't need the entire input record and all you need is few fields of it only. If most of the fields are not used, you can keep them in a separate archived storage.

3-How do you inquire this data (online/batch and what criteria is most likely to be used)? Answering this will be the key factor in answering how to store the data what parts to keep on-line and what parts to keep off-line. Oracle for example allows you to run SQL on text files without loading the files in first. This could be a huge time saver, but of course it depends on your scenario.

as per your point:

> single individuals variant data could feasibly some day require a million rows of data in a table

I really don't understand how this is possible. If it is accurate, I am not sure how it will be used. Maybe you need to separate the concepts of mere data storage from the concept of which parts of the data will be used. If you understand more about how the data will be used, you may be able to cut down the number of rows by aggregation or a similar technique.

In short much analysis is required for before a solution can be found. The guiding principles are:

1-Know your data well

2-Cut down on row size by keeping the needed columns only and linking to off-line storage when possible

3-Cut down on total row numbers by aggregation when possible

4-Use table partitioning and avoid excessive indexing

5-Know how the users need to use this data

6-Consider loading data as it arrives

7-You are probably going to need a star schema (fact and dimensions) to speed queries, but we can't tell by just the information provided

Answer (score 2):

For (1), look for common things, you may be surprised with its extent. Thats the only way to solve size problem. That is how all normalization and even compression works: find patterns (a.k.a. common stuff), store it at one place, replace values with references at every place its used.

Another solution for (1), use file system instead of database wherever you can to save blob data. In oracle you can even index to search them later.

For (2), use views (more maintainable) or stored-procedures (less maintainable).

Another solution for (2), may be its better to build separate small applications for each set of your users. I assume you are not expecting millions of users, just a few hundred or a few thousand. Making 10 separate projects is more maintainable than a large one. Alternatively you can divide on bases of modules, in .net a dll is a module, in database a schema is. Use this solution if you don't find much in common among your users, if you do then use normalization.

Don't forget fundamental technique of indexing your tables!

Answer (score 1):

I have made use of external files and link to them. This will greatly reduce the strain on the DB. You will need to find a way to get the data back out of the file, but it can be done pretty simply with JavaScript or PHP.